# Information on? for? about?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which is grammatically correct?

> A visit was made to local supermarket to observe and collect information **for/on/about** the fat contents of vegetable spread and butter available in the store.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to ELL! When you ask a question, be sure to include the same issue as in your title (you present 3 options in your title, and 2 in your question). In this case, I have edited it for you.

Answer (score 2):

According to Oxford's dictionary, both "information on" and "information about" can be used.

[image]

I would also use an indefinite article in your exemplary sentence: "a local supermarket".

Comment: The phrase "information for" can be used as well, but that generally means something different, and would be structured accordingly.